# Buffering the raw data from a QResource?

Tags: c++, qt

I am creating a 3ds model loader using Qt.

I want to take advantage of the Qt resource system and use it for loading models and such.

I would like to do syntax similar to this:

```
Mesh* MeshLoader::loadMesh(const QString& resource) {
    QResource qResource(resource);
    QResource::registerResource(resource); 
    SomeBuffer buffer(qResource.data())
    while (!buffer.eof()) { 
        // Process the file
    }
    QResource::unregisterResource(resource);
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you're only going to read it once, buffering it doesn't make sense. Just use a plain file.

Comment: Are you planning on storing models within your executable then?

Comment: Well, with something like a 3DS file, which takes some time to process the file in itself, I would cache it and use it for later (say, if a person exits and enters a room again, there would be no need to reparse the scene, as it is already cached). Some things like static meshes, that are not written or modified ever unless major releases, would ideally be cached. I'm sure there would be ways of caching it by using the file in itself, and I guess I can just use the good old fopen calls and what nots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And what's the problem with the code you included in you post?

Just as a note: you can use the Qt resource notation (the leading : in the path) with pretty much every Qt data/stream reader. For example you can use QFile(":/someresource"). With QFile and QDataStream I think (but maybe I'm wrong) you can read only chunks of the file without loading the whole resource and blocking the thread during reading. If it blocks the main-thread you can always use QRunnable or QThread to load resources in background.

For the buffering: I don't know any caching solution built into Qt (except in the networking related parts), so you should probably implement it for yourself.

This way you can build a MyResource class which loads the target resource in a background thread and notifies with signal/slot when it's finished and can cache the resource's data the way you want.

Comment: Oh gotcha. Thank you very much for this post!